# making a single xdf files from 2 other xdf files

Tags: r, visual-studio, microsoft-r

I am using the RevoScaleR package in MS Visual Studio, and I'm stuck on a step.

I have one XDF file with a column called "Total_Admits_Pred". I have another XDF file with a column called "Total_Admits".

Both XDF files have the same number of rows. I would like to combine the two XDF files into a single XDF file with both of these columns. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
xdf_df1 <- rxImport("<path/to/xdf1>")
xdf_df2 <- rxImport("<path/to/xdf2>")

xdfOut <- RxXdfData("<path/to/merged/xdf>") # Should not already exist

# This assumes that xdf2 was the one containing "Total_Admits_Pred"
# and that xdf1 contained "Total_Admits", you'll have to adjust this
# based on your data.
xdf_df1[["Total_Admits_Pred"]] <- xdf_df2$Total_Admits_Pred 

# Verify the Data Frame is correct
head(xdf_df1)

# Export it
rxDataStep(inData = xdf_df1, outFile = xdfOut)
```

Comment: Just a quick question, when you write: xdf_df1[["Total_Admits_Pred"]], could you explain this syntax to me? Are you assigning Total_Admits_Pred to its own column in xdf_df1? I didn't know XDF's worked like that? Further, xdf_df2$Total_Admits_Pred, this just returns this specific column in xdf_df2? So, am I to gather then, that XDFs work exactly the same way as regular old dataframes in R, they are just stored differently? Thanks!

Comment: This answer converts the two xdf files to (in memory) data frame, then combines them. See my answer for a way to do this without reading all the data into memory.

Comment: @ThomasMoore the syntax xdf_df1[["Total_Admits_Pred"]] creates a column labelled "Total_Admits_Pred" in xdf_df1 and then appends the data from xdf_df2 into that column. Hong is write, my scriptlet reads the two XDF files into R's memory as data.frames and then does that data manipulation with standard R.

Answer (score 3):

You can add columns to an existing xdf file with `rxDataStep`:

```
xdf1 <- RxXdfData("file1.xdf")  # dataset containing Total_Admits_Pred
xdf2 <- RxXdfData("file2.xdf")  # dataset containing Total_Admits

rxDataStep(xdf1, xdf2, varsToKeep="Total_Admits_Pred", append="cols")
```

This will result in `file2.xdf` containing all its pre-existing columns, plus `Total_Admits_Pred`.

Another way is to use the dplyrXdf package:

```
devtools::install_github("RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf")

df <- data.frame(Total_Admits_Pred=xdf1$Total_Admits_Pred,
                 Total_Admits=xdf2$Total_Admits)
```

This creates an in-memory data frame with just the two columns you want. The advantage of this, over the other answer, is that it reads *only* those two columns into memory.

Comment: I understood his question as, "each xdf file only has one column", that's why I didn't reference the columns directly